# What are the methods to migrate millions of nodes and edges from 0.44 to 0.5?

Tags: migration, graph-databases, titan

I'm migrating the entire Titan graph database from 0.44 to 0.5. There are about 120 million nodes and 90 million edges that's gigabytes of data. I tried the GraphML format, but it didn't work.

Can you suggest methods to do the migration?

Comment: How many vertices/edges do you have?

Comment: There are about 120 million nodes and 90 million edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the size you are describing you would probably execute the most efficient migration by using Titan-Hadoop/Faunus.  The general process would be to:

1. Use Faunus 0.4.x to extract the data from your graph as [GraphSON](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.2/graphson-io-format.html) and store that in HDFS
2. Use Titan-Hadoop 0.5.x to read the GraphSON and write back to your storage backend.

Make sure that you've created your schema in your target backend prior to executing step 2.

As an aside, GraphML is not a good format for a graph of this size - it's will take too long and require a lot of resources if it would work at all.  You might wonder why you wouldn't use Sequence files if you are using Faunus/Titan Hadoop...the reason you can't in this case is because I believe that there were version differences between 0.4.x and 0.5.x with respect to the file format of Sequence files.  In other words, 0.5.x can't read 0.4.x sequence files.  GraphSON is readable by both versions so it makes for an ideal migration format.

Comment: I tried the method you had proposed and the idea worked for a sample graph(Wiki-Vote graph), however it didn't work for the graph which i'm trying to migrate to titan 0.5 . I keep getting error in moving the graph information into HDFS. The jobtracker gets hanged once it reaches about 19% of the mapping phase. then i tried modifying various hadoop configuration including increasing Heap space for map and reduce tasks but it didn't work. the error i get recently in jobtracker log states that : "ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus: Trying to set illegal startTime for task".

Comment: Please let me know, if you have any ideas

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error, so I'm not sure what I can offer in terms of a fix.  It sounds like an error related to hadoop configurations, but I'm not sure.  Have you tried to extract the data from 0.4 to HDFS using a sequence file instead of GraphSON?  See if that changes any of your outcome.  If the sequence file output works then you could try to convert from sequence file to GraphSON and then continue to step 2 of the migration.

Comment: @ stephen, thanks for the help, i'll try storing it in sequence files.

Comment: Faunus started throwing errors once i increased cassandra.thrift.framed.size_mb to more than 2000 MB, is there any way to overcome this situation.

Comment: I don't think that setting can exceed 2048 (cassandra limit) and even on graphs over 1B edges i've typically never needed to set it that high.  Are you getting thrift frame size exceptions that are requiring you to make that as big as you are?

Comment: yes, i was getting those same exceptions, I was finally able to get the graph in sequence file format within HDFS an hour ago. I reduced this parameter cassandra.input.split.size value from 65k to 32768 and it started working. Thanks a lot for your time and guidance. I'll proceed now on the remaining part.

Comment: @ Stephen, I've successfully converted the sequence file to graphson format. Then i created the basic schema for the graph and worked towards converting graphson to titan 0.5.2 format. In this process i keep getting this error : java.io.IOException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 . Please let me know if you have any suggestions on this.

Comment: i basically opened the new graph configuration using g = HadoopFactory.open() and executed g._(). below are the parameters 
titan.hadoop.input.format=com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.graphson.GraphSONInputFormat
titan.hadoop.input.location=Twitter_graphson/job-0

Comment: titan.hadoop.output.format=com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.cassandra.TitanCassandraOutputFormat
titan.hadoop.output.conf.storage.backend=cassandra
titan.hadoop.output.conf.storage.hostname=sv1,sv2,sv3
titan.hadoop.output.conf.storage.port=9160
titan.hadoop.output.conf.storage.cassandra.keyspace=twitter1
titan.hadoop.output.conf.storage.batch-loading=true
titan.hadoop.output.infer-schema=true
titan.hadoop.sideeffect.format=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat

Comment: hmmm - the message indicates that your GraphSON is invalid obviously.  Something isn't parseable there somehow.  I would try to validate that the GraphSON you constructed from sequence file can be read.  Perhaps, try reading it with 0.4.x and just do a simple `g.E.label.groupCount()` or something like that and see if you still get that error.  I'm not sure how you would end up with "bad" JSON in HDFS offhand.

Comment: @ Stephen, i was able to execute the command and get results for the sequence file in faunus 0.4.4. These are the results :==>mentioned    102442
==>related      33333
==>rights       2829652
==>sameAs       16238027
==>subject      17499077
==>wikiPageDisambiguates        1236947
==>wikiPageWikiLink     136558397
==>homepage     500217
==>wikiPageExternalLink 6042972
==>birthPlace   791069
==>follows      96252611
==>depiction    1601066
==>thumbnail    3015945
==>wikiPageRedirects    5963175
==>broader      1985188  .

Comment: However i keep getting the JsonObject parse error once i execute g.E.groupCount() on the converted graphson file. Please do let me know, if you have any ideas.

Comment: Just in case this is the property file i used for sequence file to graphson conversion: 
faunus.graph.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat
faunus.input.location=Twitter_out/job-0

faunus.graph.output.format=com.thinkaurelius.faunus.formats.graphson.GraphSONOutputFormat
faunus.sideeffect.output.format=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
faunus.output.location=Twitter_graphson
faunus.output.location.overwrite=true